# Does Qt3DQuickWindow exist in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt3d

Trying to get a QML 3D example to work in Python, but I can't find Qt3DQuickWindow anywhere. Is it there? Or when will it be?

Comment: I just searched and there is no support for it yet.

Comment: You need to ask on the [pyqt mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/) if you want to get a proper answer regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will post there.

Comment: 4.5 years after... still not there unfortunately